# Why am I unable to launch a URL via Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am a Selenium (Ruby) newbie.

I am trying to launch Google homepage as below:

```
@selenium = Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com", 10000);
@selenium.start
```

However, after the script runs, it launches Firefox with below URL:

```
http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/Blank.html?start=true
```

I am unable to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the keys for your hash, eg

```
Selenium::Client::Driver.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 4444, etc)
```